# Detecting termination in CP-SAT

Tags: java, or-tools, constraint-programming, cp-sat

I was exploring the CP-SAT APIs for fetching all solution for given set of constraints.

As per the API documentation, onSolutionCallback() function is called for every solution found. However if I need to find all solutions for a given model, is there a way to detect the last solution or the feasibility of no more solutions through onSolutionCallback() function or other means?

I found that searchAllSolutions() API can be used and we can set termination conditions based on time or number of solutions. Assuming I can wait unlimited amount of time, how do I detect that there are no more solutions feasible?

https://developers.google.com/optimization/cp/cp_tasks

Another related question: 
Is there any remote chance for a CP SAT solver to run into a non-deterministic state or run into infinite loops (or such) even when there is a feasible solution possible for given set of constraints?
I plan to use the CPSAT for a production usecase and hence would like to know its determinism and upper bounds for execution.

Edit: Added the second question.

Comment: I don't really understand the question, can't you wait until `searchAllSolutions` finishes?

Comment: As per my understanding, searchAllSolutions() is an asynchronous API. Solver calls onSolutionCallback() function once for every solution it find. There is no way to find if all the solutions have been found or we need to wait more time.

Comment: Actually, Solve() returns OPTIMAL when all solutions have been found, and search has terminated normally. See http://google.github.io/or-tools/python/ortools/sat/python/cp_model.html#cp_model.CpSolver.SearchForAllSolutions

Comment: I have been a noob. I misunderstood the documentation and assumed the searchAllSolutions() can return 'FEASIBLE' sometimes and I thought there was no way to force it to search all solutions.

Comment: Another related question: Is there any remote chance for a CP SAT solver to run into a non-deterministic state or run into infinite loops (or such) even when there is a feasible solution possible for given set of constraints?

Comment: Thanks Laurent Perron, Stradivari. I will add the above question in overview and you can add the answer. This way it will be useful for others in future.

Comment: @sdare Upper bounds in combinatorial-optimization are pretty uncommon. You probably started to use ortools because it's heuristics are performing good (better than some other approach you could write where you can post upper-bounds; e.g. exhaustive-search). But there is always the exponential worst-case. Depending on some very complex internals like random-restarts there is maybe even a chance of infinite-search (even if the core CDCL-SAT is *complete*). This isn't that important for the user, but you should always use time-outs and expect *some* bad runs (in production).

Comment: Thanks sascha@, Does that mean for a given set of constraints there is a remote chance that the SAT solver can run into infinite search in production, even if in past it was able to return a feasible solution for same set of constraints ?

Comment: My remarks were more target to the solve my problem A thing -> no problem. Ok, problem B is problem A without one constraint. It's easier then. The solver should have no prob..... oh it does not find a solution. These things are common in discrete-opt. Your question ` even if in past it was able to return a feasible solution for same set of constraints` sounds like asking for deterministic behaviour. If the solver is deterministic, using the same hardware, ortools version,ortools options, model / problem should ways lead to the same solution. See ortools docs. ortools has undeterministic modes